# Delete all duplicate rows Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with two columns: Date and Name. I want to delete all rows that are exact duplicates, leaving only unique values.

Here is my code (which doesn't work):

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Dim rng As Range
Dim counter As Long, numRows As Long

With ActiveSheet
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B" & LastRowB)
End With
numRows = rng.Rows.Count

For counter = numRows To 1 Step -1
    If rng.Cells(counter) Like rng.Cells(counter) - 1 Then
        rng.Cells(counter).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

It's "Like rng.Cells(counter)-1" that seems to be the cause- I get "Type Mismatch".

Comment: Try `rng.Cells(counter - 1)`

Comment: Have you tried going to Data -> Remove Duplicates? Or do you need to use VBA for this particular application?

Comment: The above coding is part of a procedure that does much more work on a fairly big worksheet, so I want to do the whole job with one click of a button.

Comment: You have not accepted any of the answer for all the questions you have asked so far. Is there any reason ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There's a `RemoveDuplicates` method that you could use:

```
Sub DeleteRows()

    With ActiveSheet
        Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
        Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Great. Please click the check box to 'accept' this answer if you found it useful. It helps me rack up those sweet, sweet karma points :)

Comment: It also gets rid of the blank rows. Excellent!

Comment: How can I have it delete the whole row?

Comment: can i make `Array(1, 2)` as variable of array because it gives me an error wrong argument

Comment: @mhmdshawqi you could try taking a count of the entire table of data, then after remove duplicates, do another count, then use EntireRow.delete on the range

Answer (score 2):

The duplicate values in any column can be deleted with a simple for loop.

```
Sub remove()
Dim a As Long
For a = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A1:A" & a), Cells(a, 1)) > 1 Then Rows(a).Delete
Next
End Sub
```