# How can I remove duplicate rows and reversed-order duplicate rows in VBA-Excel

Tags: excel, duplicates, vba

-updated -

I wonder how to remove duplicate rows based on values in two columns, where duplicates can occur in reversed order too. I want to remove whole rows, not only duplicate cells in columns. I have searched the forum but cant find the exact answer to this.

If the data looks like:

```
AA
AB
BA
CA
AC
```

I want to keep:

```
AA
AB
CA
```

So far I have only seen code to remove one-way duplicates (e.g. [Delete all duplicate rows Excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988816/delete-all-duplicate-rows-excel-vba) ), which would not remove any rows from the example above.

I will need to calculate the distance between two named points, so what row I keep does not matter. Maybe I should also specify that the format is e.g. A1 and A2 (letter + number) in each cell, thus A1+A2 and A2+A1 would be a duplicate. Not sure if this matters.

Does anyone know or can hint me in the right direction?

Thanks
Lisarv

Comment: Do you always want to keep the first occurrence, or is there a different rule on which should be kept.

Comment: No, it does not matter which row, see my updated question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you already have a solution based on a **single** column, we will find a way to apply that solution.  With data in columns **A** and **B**, in **C1** enter:

```
=IF(A1<B1,A1 & CHAR(1) & B1,B1 & CHAR(1) & A1)
```

and copy down.  Then apply your solution to column **C**:

[image]

Note:

We use CHAR(1) to prevent accidental matches.

**EDIT#1**

Here is a pure VBA solution without using column **C**:

```
Sub RowKiller()
   Dim N As Long, C() As String, i As Long
   Dim aa As String, bb As String, cc As String
   Dim s As String
   s = Chr(1)
   N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
   ReDim C(1 To N)

   For i = 1 To N
      aa = Cells(i, 1).Value
      bb = Cells(i, 2).Value
      If aa < bb Then
         C(i) = aa & s & bb
      Else
         C(i) = bb & s & aa
      End If
   Next i

   For i = N To 2 Step -1
      cc = C(i)
      For j = i - 1 To 1 Step -1
         If cc = C(j) Then Rows(i).Delete
      Next j
   Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This was another way around it than I expected, thus I will keep the question open for a bit more. I was hoping for vba-code, as I will need to redo this and other operations a number of times and want to avoid manual steps. But, it does work, though by changing the commas to semi-colons! So indeed thanks for that @Gary

Comment: @Lisarv  I also will look for a solution without the "helper" column.