# Data copy to 2 different sheets depending on cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 main sheets ( "kids" and "parents") and another 3 sheets that I use for data input. What I want the code to do is to copy the values of the 3 sheets from column A TO L and transfer them to the main sheets depending on the value chosen in column D. So if I insert data to one of the 3 sheets and I have as a value in column D "kids" it should transfer it to SHEET "KIDS" if I choose value "parents" the data should go to sheet "parents". In any case, I do want it to remove duplicates and not copy the same data each time I open the file.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
 Dim i As Long, lastRow As Long, ws As Worksheet
Sheets("Kids").Range("A3:L500").ClearContents
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> ("Kids") Then
        ws.Activate
        lastRow = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 2 To lastRow
                If ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = "Kids" Then
                    Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Kids").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "D").Value = "Parents" Then
                    Rows(i).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Parents").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)


                End If
            Next i
    End If
Next ws
End Sub
```

So this is the code I have used but it doesn't remove duplicates for main sheet "parents". Something is wrong...

Comment: You should say by posting any sample picture and code what you tried. Visit [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) page for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not conveying total situation of your problem as mentioned by @Nicolas. However to help you with your problem go to the code posted by @fbonetti in the following thread to remove duplicates.

[delete-all-duplicate-rows-excel-vba:][Delete all duplicate rows Excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988816/)

Further to transfer Copy Data to Another Excel WorkBook Based on Criteria Using VBA to do is the following:
1.  Identify data in a workbook sheet based on a text criterium and a date criterium or condition using a looping process
2.  Select the specific data which meets the two or multiple conditions
3.  Copy the identified data
4.  Open another workbook
5.  Find the first blank row in a specific worksheet in the workbook
6.  Paste the data in the identified blank or empty row – erow
7.  Save the workbook
8.  Close the workbook
Go through the link mentioned below.
  http://www.exceltrainingvideos.com/copy-data-to-another-excel-workbook-based-on-criteria-using-vba/

HTH