# Excel - A macro to group by column & sum values for big Range (15K rows)

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I have an excel sheet with 2 columns and can have upto 15K rows. I need to sum values, group by first and second column. Currently I am using the followinn macro, the code is copying the data across a new sheet, sorting it and removing the duplicates while adding the count if a match found. I have tested it for 500 rows items to so far and it takes couple of minutes and I am worried of the time taken if there are more rows (as there can be up to 15K rows).

```
Sub consolidateData()   

Dim lRow As Long   
Dim ItemRow1, ItemRow2 As String   
Dim lengthRow1, lengthRow2 As String   

    Columns("A:C").Select   
    Selection.Copy   

    Sheets("Sheet3").Select   

    Range("A1").Select   
    ActiveSheet.Paste   

    Cells.Select   
    Selection.Sort _   
        Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _   
        Key2:=Range("C2"), Order2:=xlDescending, _   
        Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, _   
        MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _   
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal   

    lRow = 2   
    Do While (Cells(lRow, 1) <> "")   

        ItemRow1 = Cells(lRow, "A")   
        ItemRow2 = Cells(lRow + 1, "A")   

        lengthRow1 = Cells(lRow, "C")   
        lengthRow2 = Cells(lRow + 1, "C")   

        If ((ItemRow1 = ItemRow2) And (lengthRow1 = lengthRow2)) Then   
            Cells(lRow, "B") = Cells(lRow, "B") + Cells(lRow + 1, "B")   
            Rows(lRow + 1).Delete   

        Else   
            lRow = lRow + 1   
        End If   
    Loop   
End Sub
```

Could you please suggest if there is a quickest way to do it.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which bit is slow? You may want to have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros

Comment: Do you just need the sum or do you need the data sorted? Also, 15k rows isn't that big... What's making this so time-intensive?

Comment: Try Range.RemoveDuplicates. Looking at your code, I think that calling Row.Delete for individual Rows must be the bottleneck.

Comment: Or read the whole thing into an Array of Variants, write a custom function to sort your data and remove duplicates from this array and write back the data into Range.Value

Comment: Did you try to use a pivot table ?

Answer (score 1):

Thera are a few things you would do to improve your performance:

There is a *RemoveDuplica* method you could use, as of [SOF Delete all duplicate row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988816/delete-all-duplicate-rows-excel-vba):

```
    Sub DeleteRows()
        With ActiveSheet
          Set Rng = Range("A1", Range("B1").End(xlDown))
          Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2), Header:=xlYes
        End With
    End Sub
```

If you use Preformated table it will be easy to fill up a new sheet with the information you need

When apropriate, always use the code below to improve your funcion/sub performance:

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Might be better if you copy only the columns that should be grouped by, then you do the *sumif* into the value column.

Hope it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick way to have your macro faster. It would stop animation and a few other perks. :)
However, it would be a great idea to rebuild your code from the beginning, avoinding the selects.

```
Sub consolidateData()   

    Dim lRow As Long   
    Dim ItemRow1, ItemRow2 As String   
    Dim lengthRow1, lengthRow2 As String   

        call onstart
        Columns("A:C").Select   
        Selection.Copy   

        Sheets("Sheet3").Select   

        Range("A1").Select   
        ActiveSheet.Paste   

        Cells.Select   
        Selection.Sort _   
            Key1:=Range("A2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _   
            Key2:=Range("C2"), Order2:=xlDescending, _   
            Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=1, _   
            MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _   
            DataOption1:=xlSortNormal   

        lRow = 2   
        Do While (Cells(lRow, 1) <> "")   

            ItemRow1 = Cells(lRow, "A")   
            ItemRow2 = Cells(lRow + 1, "A")   

            lengthRow1 = Cells(lRow, "C")   
            lengthRow2 = Cells(lRow + 1, "C")   

            If ((ItemRow1 = ItemRow2) And (lengthRow1 = lengthRow2)) Then   
                Cells(lRow, "B") = Cells(lRow, "B") + Cells(lRow + 1, "B")   
                Rows(lRow + 1).Delete   

            Else   
                lRow = lRow + 1   
            End If   
        Loop   
        call onende
    End Sub


    Public Sub OnEnd()

        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = True
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
        ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False

        Application.StatusBar = False

    End Sub

    Public Sub OnStart()

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.AskToUpdateLinks = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
        ThisWorkbook.Date1904 = False

        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

    End Sub
```

Comment: Many thanks for response and the  tips, but how much time would it save?

Comment: Depending on how much time your application runs, but I would estimate about 40% - 80%.

Comment: Great, I have now updated the code as per your suggestion but getting some errors, on the Sorting code "Cells.Select......" it gives me the Run time error 1004. Application-defined or object defined error. Can you please assist.