# VBA to delete Duplicate Records Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to delete duplicate rows from my table and I thought this was straightforward enough looking at other examples online. Unfortunately, I am getting a type mismatch error on my variable.
Also, I want the first instance from the bottom to be deleted not the first instance. So if row 5 and 27 are duplicates, I want row 27 to be deleted.

Here is my code:

```
Sub DeleteDuplicateRows()

Dim Rng As Range
With Worksheets("Database")

Set Rng = Range("C1", Range("Q1").End(xlDown))
    Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(3, 17), Header:=xlYes
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete all duplicate rows Excel vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988816/delete-all-duplicate-rows-excel-vba)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array(1, 15) is column C and column Q **within** range C:Q.

```
Sub DeleteDuplicateRows()
    Dim Rng As Range

    With Worksheets("Database")
        Set Rng = .Range("C1", .Range("Q1").End(xlDown))
        Rng.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 15), Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is this making sure `C` and `Q` aren't duplicates or is it `C` or `Q`?

Comment: C **and** Q. If you want C **or** Q then you need to do it twice; once for C and once for Q.